# Why is my Filter not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a filter that will show real-time search. Basically it will hide the other trs of the table except for those which matches the input of an input field. It is working fine, but it stopped working when I tried to search table within the table. I don't have a clue about the problem.

My HTML:

```
<table class="w3-table w3-striped w3-bordered w3-border w3-margin-top" id="mainTable" width="100%">
<tr class="tr">
<td class="td-head">bnc</td>
<td style="text-align: right"><button class="w3-btn w3-teal w3-round-xxlarge arrow" onclick="toggle('Tcol1')" > <span>More </span></button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
  <table class="w3-table subTable" id="Tcol1" style="display: none; font-size: 80%;">
    <tr>
        <td class="va-bottom"> Branch Code </td><td class="w3-right td-big"> bc02 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> IP Adress </td><td class="w3-right"> ip03 </td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td> IP Phone </td><td class="w3-right"> ipp04 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Net Agent </td><td class="w3-right"> na005 </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   </td>
   </tr>

<tr class="tr">
<td class="td-head">bn</td>
<td style="text-align: right"><button class="w3-btn w3-teal w3-round-xxlarge arrow" onclick="toggle('Tcol2')" > <span>More </span></button></td>
 </tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
  <table class="w3-table subTable" id="Tcol2" style="display: none; font-size: 80%;">
    <tr>
        <td class="va-bottom"> Branch Code </td><td class=" w3-right td-big"> bc02 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> IP Adress </td><td class="w3-right"> ip03 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> IP Phone </td><td class="w3-right"> ipp04 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Net Agent </td><td class="w3-right"> na005 </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table></div>
```

My JavaScript:

```
 function myFunction() {
 var input, filter, table, tr, td, subTable, subtr, subtd, i;
 input = document.getElementById("myInput");
 filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
 table = document.getElementById("mainTable");
 subTable = document.getElementByClassName("subTable");
 tr = table.getElementsByClassName("tr");
 subtr = subTable.getElementsByTagName("tr");

for (i = 0; i < tr.length || i< subtr.length; i++) {
  td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
  subtd = subtr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];

    if (td, subtd) {
        if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1 || subtd.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
     } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
     }
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: `subTable` is an array-like collection ([`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)) of elements with the class `subTable`

Comment: Is it the subTable's you want to search, not the mainTable?

Comment: I want to search both mainTable and subTable. If the result matches with either one of them, it will hide the other unmatched mainTable